# can not access my ubuntu server through putty

Tags: server, ssh, lubuntu, aws, putty

I was able to access my ubuntu server through putty. but suddenly it stops working. Server is working fine . I can access through aws console

[image]

but when I try to access through putty I receive this error.

I don't know why server refusing key it is same what i was using before

[image]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @user68186 version is 20.04.3

Comment: The key could expire.

Comment: I also tried new one but not working

Comment: This question is rather *unclear*; you mention Server but also mention Lubuntu in *tags* which means it's a desktop system and not a server. Adding desktop packages to server system can change parts of the system. Also 20.04.3 shows you're very far behind on upgrades as 20.04.5 is rolling out to installed systems **now**, & 20.04.3 implies you've not applied upgrades since at least Feb-2022 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/ which shows the ISO release date but installed systems get the upgrades weeks before ISO release date).